If I work as an independent contractor for an insurance inspection company, can I be sued for negligence for anything that happens to the property?
I was recently hired by a small company based in another state to conduct commercial property insurance inspections as well as homeowners insurance and will be inspecting interiors like MEP as well as cookery and cooking space if it's a restaurant. I am worried that since I don't have a professional errors and omissions insurance policy, can I be held liable if anything were to go wrong at the places that I inspect like a fire were to start or an event that causes damage and the insurance company denies the claim for whatever reason? The insurance company that receives the report SHOULD be willing to cover anything that goes wrong since they are the "insurance" company that gets paid thousands of dollars each year by the customer and I shouldn't have to worry that much as long as I do my job as carefully as I can, right? Especially if I just acted within my realm of work duties such as filling out all the information that was given to me on the forms, taking pictures of all the main areas of the property, etc.? Also, I'm not entirely sure it's really an "inspection", it's more like they just give me a form with questions to ask the insured to fill out as well as take pictures of the property.
The company that I was hired by doesn't have a website and I was hired after applying on indeed and the owner emails me the work assignments. He said I will be filling out a W-9 and be on payroll after I submit my first completed assignment. Should I ask for the company's EIN number so that I can know the company's identity and where they are based or can that be determined once a payment has been direct deposited into my bank account? Would it ridiculous of me to ask him if he can just venmo or cash app me the payments for each assignment I complete? I am paid on a per assignment basis.
EDIT: Also, I was wondering, can I add this waiver at the bottom of each report that I will submit to further lessen my liability in case of any legal trouble:
Waiver of Liability
The information provided in this inspection report by [Your Name], the inspector, is based on visual observations and the conditions apparent at the time of the inspection. While reasonable care has been taken to provide accurate and comprehensive findings, no warranty or guarantee is expressed or implied regarding the future condition or safety of the property or systems inspected. [Your Name], the inspector, assumes no liability for any errors, omissions, or discrepancies within the scope of this inspection, nor for any damages or loss resulting from decisions made based on this report. By accepting and using this report, the recipient acknowledges and agrees that [Your Name] and the inspection company shall not be held liable for any damages or losses arising from the use of this report. Any liability is limited to the cost of the inspection service provided.

Legal question aside, this has all the earmarks of an employment scam. The company does not exist and their goal is to take your money, steal your identity and/or use you to launder stolen funds. Run away.

Also, if you are truly an independent contractor, then you are not on payroll, you would be submitting invoices and being paid on those.

I think insurance companies need to be licensed in each state to do business there. Check if they're listed on the state's department of insurance.

I see, I just added a waiver to the end of my post, do you think I can add that to each report I submit to lessen my liability in case of any legal trouble?

A contractor is responsible for their own acts and omissions
So, yes, if you are a contractor and you are negligent, the wronged party can sue you directly rather than suing your principal.

What about the doctrine of privity of contract?

As a practical matter, an inspector almost always has a contract that waives liability for ordinary negligence or limits recovery to the amount of the fee for the job.

@ohwilleke not in Australia for a contract with a consumer - statutory guarantee that services will provided with “due care and skill” - negligently supplies services aren’t.
